# How do I connect to Oracle Database in excel VBA using Window Authentication

Tags: excel, vba, oracle

I have a VBA excel application that was working in Office 2016, after migrating to M365, the application stopped working

First I changed my reference from ActiveX 2.8 to 6.1. I started getting error “provider could not be found”

I installed Oracle client 19c (64 bit) and now i an getting ORA-01017 invalid username/password; login denied

I am trying to login with Windows authentication and it used to work with office 2016.

My connection string - “Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=Data;OSAuthent=1”

PS- i dont know if it was referencing a TNS file

Comment: "i dont know if it was referencing a TNS file"  - you need to figure that part out.  Most likely it was.   Make sure your driver matches your Office install - if you have 64-bit Office then you need the 64-bit driver,  likewise for 32-bit Office.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Williams . I confirmed it is referencing a TNS file. The driver and office are both 64-bit. Looks like it wants me to provide login credentials but i need it to use windows authentication

Comment: Are you able to connect using a hard-coded username/password?  Maybe check the requirements here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ntqrf/about-windows-authentication-protocols.html#GUID-B49C877B-53BB-4F79-A64B-73012188CC85  You need to make sure your sqlnet.ora file has the right content.